# Rails 3.1 secure_password and Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec-rails

I'm toying around with secure_password in rails 3.1. I was writing model rspec testing but couldn't figure out how to call the authenticate method provided by the secure_password in rails 3.1.

```
describe "authentication" do
  before(:each) do
    @user = User.create!(@attr)
  end
....

  describe "it should check credentials" do
    describe "it should return false on an invalid password" do
      @user.authenticate("wrongpass").should_be false
    end
  end
end
```

Any idea? Note i'm using has_secure_password in my user model

here is the lastest error my console gives me:

/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing': undefined method`authenticate' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 0):

authenticate returns the user if password provided is correct or nil. If you have everything setup properly (don't forget to add a password_digest column) this should be working:

```
@user.authenticate("wrongpass").should be_nil
```

Update: according to the error message you added, @user is nil so you should check that.

Comment: Hey James, thanks for the answer! Unfortunately it's not quite it. According to the github repo, authenticate should return false if it fails to authenticate, so false or be_nil should both work. I also have a successful test to check that @user responds to :password_digest. I will continue to look and let you know.

Comment: Please note that the test "@user responds to :password_digest" tests for the attribute being part of the db schema, not for the has_secure_password line in the model.